# Unable to get regex working

Tags: regex

I have a third party application that lets me enter a regular expression to validate the user input in a text box. I need user to input the data in this format `C:64GB, F:128GB H:32GB`. This is the regex i wrote:

```
\b[A-z]{1}[:]?\d*(GB|gb)\b
```

This regex works fine but it only validates the first block. so if i write `C:64GB F:128`, it marks the input as valid. it does not check for `F:128` as that makes the input invalid. it should be `C:64GB F:128GB`.

When I change my regex to `^\b[A-z]{1}[:]?\d*(GB|gb)\b$`, it only allows me to enter `C:64GB`.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `[A-z]{1}` you don't need the `{1}` quantifier

Comment: It's not clear what is the user id format. Could you please write some examples and counterexamples?

Comment: Should all segments have a comma after them, or is it only after the first one or optional?  Only the first one if it is C:?

Comment: Is `Gb` not valid, since you explicitly check for `GB|gb`?

Comment: It is valid and i have added Gb and gB to valid list. I could not get case-insensitive working

Comment: If you did so by listing all possibilites `GB|Gb|gB|gb`, you may want to [read up on regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and change it to `[gG][bB]` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(\W*[A-Za-z]:?\d+(?:GB|gb)\W*)+$
```

Comment: this expression works fine but i need it to be valid if user separates multiple drives by space or a comma or a newline. Right now it only works with space. this was why i was using \b. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: ok try my updated regex now. It will work with any non-word character i.e. space, comma, colon, semicolon etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `i` case insensitive flag to help simplify the call

```
/^([A-Z]:?\d+GB[\s,]*)+$/i
```

here's a [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mJ3rP9/1)

This will be quite permissive with whitespace/commas thanks to `[\s,]*`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so: `^[A-Z]:?\d+(GB|gb),( [A-Z]:?\d+(GB|gb)){2}$`. This will expect to match the entire pattern. You can see a working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/hE9dK7/1).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the RegEx is eager. It will find the first match and then stop. You need to loop through all the matches or apply a Global modifier (which finds all the matches)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will be valid because it just look for at least 1 valid occurrence of the regex equivalent, and as you saw it, your first occurrence validating it, the regex is valid. If you want all your users inputs to be checked you should split your input string into several occurrences of the regex equivalent and check them one by one. Or do the equivalent with a regex, and that would give this :

```
^([A-Z]:?\d+[Gg][Bb] ?)+$
```

Side notes :

- I removed the {1} after your [A-Z] because it's the regex default behavior,
- I transformed your \b to ^ and $ because you need to control the full string and not part of it
- I removed the [] around the : because it was useless (you want many values between only 1 value)
- I added the space as a separator, but you can change it with whichever character pleases you
- I replaced your (GB|gb) by a [Gg][Bb] so it will not be case sensitive on this piece of your user input